# from txt table to matrix in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, matrix

I'm trying to analyze data for my work and trying to read frequency (pwm) matrix from a txt file containing multiple tables to create consensus sequence in short:

```
A
1872.00 590.00  3339.00 6805.00 0.00    0.00    6805.00 1917.00
1821.00 5138.00 1992.00 207.00  0.00    0.00    0.00    1391.00
2236.00 246.00  1386.00 192.00  0.00    0.00    0.00    2420.00
877.00  1667.00 87.00   0.00    6805.00 6805.00 0.00    1077.00
B
11369.00    11735.00    3157.00 1226.00 26720.00    29957.00    274.00  29221.00    30645.00    30125.00    13752.00    10200.00
6380.00 2568.00 2096.00 26587.00    3312.00 414.00  391.00  761.00  349.00  595.00  5299.00 6905.00
7434.00 8816.00 24214.00    607.00  184.00  1196.00 386.00  999.00  366.00  502.00  5884.00 5934.00
6843.00 8907.00 2559.00 3606.00 1810.00 459.00  30975.00    1045.00 666.00  804.00  7091.00 8987.00
C
1449.00 688.00  4036.00 8832.00 0.00    96.00   8832.00 2770.00
3929.00 5585.00 2483.00 194.00  0.00    0.00    0.00    2369.00
2290.00 103.00  2197.00 1078.00 0.00    0.00    0.00    2417.00
1164.00 3247.00 116.00  66.00   8832.00 8832.00 0.00    1276.00
```

So I wrote this to read the file at first:

```
*with open("t.txt") as tx:
        for line in tx:
            values = line.strip("\n").split("\t")
            print(values)*
```

to get a matrix afterwards. I get the output correctly but when I try to create a matrix all of the ~1200 values merge into 1 matrix but I need every 4 of them to be 1 some kinda like this:

```
C
1449.00 688.00  4036.00 8832.00 0.00    96.00   8832.00 2770.00
3929.00 5585.00 2483.00 194.00  0.00    0.00    0.00    2369.00
2290.00 103.00  2197.00 1078.00 0.00    0.00    0.00    2417.00
1164.00 3247.00 116.00  66.00   8832.00 8832.00 0.00    1276.00
```

but instead I get this:

```
['X']
['0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00']
['0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '4.00', '2.00', '10.00', '0.00', '9.00']
['0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '6.00', '8.00', '0.00', '10.00', '1.00']
['10.00', '10.00', '10.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00']
```

And i can't :). I tried to check lines as rows by writing **print(values[0])** but it gave me every 1st one of the lists.

How am I supposed to read a matrix correctly by not getting rows as lists and every matrix to be seperated from each other?

Comment: @BtcSources I edited, hope it's clear now.

Comment: no i mean, i need to assign X as the header and next 4 rows to be its matrix. But I have multiple tables in the file so they are all assigned into 1 matrix, not seperatedly.

Comment: In your question there's no code for how you group different lines from a list to consider them the same matrix, nor how you retrieve it then. This way we can't help you.

Comment: that's because i don't know how :))

Comment: You said "I am getting this instead". How are you getting "this"? Which code do you execute for this output? What have you done?